# If I edit a Python file with IDLE and try to run that in the Revit Python Shell, it fails with Unexpected Token errors. Why?

Tags: python-idle, revit-api, revitpythonshell

I learning to use the Revit Python Shell addin and have come across a problem that I am hoping someone knows the answer to.

Initially, I would create a Python script using Notepad and then load that file into the interactive dialog for Revit Python Shell. That script would work fine.

I then discovered that Windows had a right-click option to edit the file with the IDLE editor. After that, RPS would return errors about "Unexpected Tokens" when I tried to run the script file. These tokens varied from " ", to "", to "".

Suspecting hidden formatting codes, I was able to "clean" the file using MS Word's option to "Open & Repair". After "cleaning" the Python script worked correctly.

Since editing a script with IDLE is much friendlier than Notepad, is there a way to stop IDLE from embedding hidden codes in the file?

Or is there a way to get RPS to successfully run a script edited with IDLE?

Sincerely;
Michelle

Comment: What is 'from " ", to "", to "".' (from space to nothing to nothing) supposed to mean?  The only thing IDLE does to a file without being asked is to remove spaces at the end of lines and possibly fiddle with line endings.  There are no 'hidden formatting codes.  Are you using Windows or Linux?  Revit supports either python 2.7 or 3.4, so there could be a version issue.  If you use any non-ascii characters or ascii control chars other than tab and return, there might be an issue.  Does revit say what 'tokens' is does not like?

Comment: Hmm...It looks like the StackOverflow website editor stripped out text between the quotes. I will try again. One item was " " - quote, space, quote. Another was "<newline>" - quote, "<", the word "newline", ">", quote

Comment: I reran the problem file and here are some of the errors:
Syntax Error: unexpected token '<newline>' (line 56)
Syntax Error: unexpected token '<newline>' (line 56)
Syntax Error: unexpected token '<indent>' (line 56)

Keep in mind this code ran fine without changes once it was "cleaned" by MS Word

Comment: Did your file run in IDLE (by clicking F5, for instance) or python itself?  Can you post line 56 between backticks? `print('line with \n embedded newline')`  Can you run this in IDLE Shell, then in revit?

Comment: After editing a file, try running it directly with Python:  In Command Prompt window, enter `py path/file.py` (assuming you installed the recommended py launcher.